# Restoring a specific file from a commit

Tags: git, git-gui

I'm using Git with GitGUI.

I did a commit to several files (and have since committed again) and now I see a test is not working. I checked out some commits and found the culprit. I now want to restore the changes made to a specific file, back to a certain commit. How can I do that?

A preferred solution will also keep the latest commits in the tree (so I can re-implement them well this time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a revision and filename to [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to check out a particular version of that file:

```
git checkout abc123 -- filename
```

Now your working copy will have the version of `filename` from commit `abc123`, and you can commit that in order to restore back to that version of that file.